# Is it possible to create a 2D vector of structs?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, struct

So far I have set up a 2D vector of ints (the code below, working) but what I really want is a 2D vector array of the struct called 'small_tile'.

Here I want to be populating the texture int of the struct with data from a txt file. Later I will also populate the other data values 'tile_x, tile_y, r, c'.

I hope my question is clear

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

struct smallTile
{
    int tile_x;
    int tile_y;
    int r;
    int c;
    int texture; // 0=grass, 1=sand, 2=... (get this data from txt file)
};

int main()
{
    int SMALL_TILE_VECTOR_ROWS = 5;
    int SMALL_TILE_VECTOR_COLUMNS = 6;

    //Create vector array: 5x6 containing nothing:
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > vvint(SMALL_TILE_VECTOR_ROWS, std::vector<int>(SMALL_TILE_VECTOR_COLUMNS));

    //Fill vector with file information. 
    std::ifstream file ("levelMap.txt");
    for(int r = 0; r < vvint.size(); r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < vvint.at(0).size(); c++)
        {
            file >> vvint[r][c];
        }
    }
    file.close();

    //cout out the data inside the vector array so I can see it's working:
    for(int r = 0; r < vvint.size(); r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < vvint.at(0).size(); c++)
        {
            std::cout<< vvint[r][c] << " ";
        }
        std::cout<< "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::vector <smallTile> smalltiles;
```

// What is the problem?

Comment: I swear I tried that before and I got some super crazy error, I tried again just now and it worked. Thanks :)